# Can we disable the shutter button halfway pressing autofocus on A6500?

Tags: autofocus, shutter-release

With Sony A6500's touchscreen we can autofocus the desired subject. But when shutter release is pressed halfway, the camera focuses again canceling the previous focus. So, can't this - autofocus by pressing shutter halfway - be disabled?

Answer (score 3):

Set those parameters in menu:

```
Pre-AF: Off*

AF w/ shutter: Off*
```

And do not rely only on touch screen. Maybe set back button focus is wise

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the touch screen focus for still images is that you set the focus point via the screen, either by a single touch in screen mode, or by dragging in viewfinder mode.

This only positions the focus point, the actual focussing is done when you half press the shutter.

(see: [α6500 Help Guide](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1640/v1/en/contents/TP0001212156.html))